# How can I to check datalayer event using Nightwatchjs

Tags: nightwatch.js, data-layers

is it possible to get datalayer event using Nightwatchjs on click some link on web page, when new page open occured?

It's not problem to get data when page in browser by click some link do not changed. But if it's changed events in datalayer on click is cleared and not to available on new page.

Could it's solved by some js code?

Comment: It's really hard to comprehend the question, could you check the syntax and grammar?

Comment: 1. Click on some control in browser.
2. Then new page is opening in browser.
3. There's no events from previous page on new page's datalayer.

How I can get events in datalayer from previous page using Nightwatchjs test script if it's closing before I check this events? (like 'eventClick')